# Windows Form Closed but not destroyed

Tags: windows, forms, destructor

In my Windows Form application when I close a form (which is derived from a base form), its FormClosing and FormClosed Events fire but destructor never fires off. It still keeps the memory occupied.

Any ideas on how to destroy the form completely when it is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not destroyed that means the Garbage Collector doesn't think it should be destroyed.

This basically means that you're either:

1. Holding a reference to the object somewhere
2. Have the object listening to an event (That's also a kind of reference to the object)

The garbage collector won't free the Form until there are no references to it.

If you have important resources you want to dispose of, make it `IDisposable`, and use the Dispose method.

Comment: Thanks for your response Yachai, I am doing the cleanup job at the FormClosed Event but it still holds the same memory even after closing it. This form is an internal form and so, closing it doesn't close the application.

Answer (score 0):

Destructors (or more correctly, finalizers - there are no destructors in .NET) are not guaranteed to be executed in .NET - objects may be cleaned up at the whim of the runtime **or even never**. You cannot rely on your finalizer method ever being called.

If you need to do something when your form is closed, handle the Closed event.

If you need to release an unmanaged resource (e.g. close an open file), add this logic to the Dispose() method.

If you are worried about memory use, do not worry about memory use. The runtime manages memory automatically based on its own logic.

Reference:  [Garbage Collection (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx)